# Insert statement in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm improving in using the Hibernate and Spring frameworks. My question is very simple: I have a dropdown on a jsp page that is populated from the database thus and a textbox that accepts input to be inserted into database based on the values selected in the dropdown:

JSP code:

```
<tr>
                    <td><form:label path="ownerName" name = "ownerName">Select Overdraft User:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:select path="ownerName" items = "${addMembersListToDropdown}"></form:select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="creditLimit">Enter an Amount:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="creditLimit"/></td>
                </tr>
```

My quest is this: how do I write the query statement in the Dao class to do this insertion? I am very new to this so I'm inexperienced in calling jsp parameters within the j2ee classes.

My sample DAO implementation class:

```
@Override
    public void saveCyclosUsers(CyclosUsers cyclosUsers) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO lower_credit ownerName' = +'owner_name');
    }
```

The pseudo-code I intend writing is: `INSERT INTO lower_credit WHERE the value selected from the dropdown  = owner_name`.

Comment: you need to lookup basic syntax for inserting into db

Comment: retrieving form parameters is covered at length in spring mvc documentation, check there

Comment: Please to help out kindly indicate with a link to a good tutorial. Thanks.